# React - Error using variable on a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React, so be gentle with me, I am a rookie. I have this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import HttpHandler from './../services/HttpHandler';
import Podcast from './Podcast/Podcast';

class Master extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.api = new HttpHandler();
        this.podList = this.api.getAllPodcasts();
        this.http = "";
        this.api.getHttpResponse(function(responseData){
            var datos = responseData;
            this.http = datos;
        }, function(error){
            this.http = error;
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Master</h1>
                <ul>
                    {this.podList.map((podcast) => <li>{podcast}</li>)}
                </ul>
                <p>API Response: {this.http}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
// ========================================

export default Master;
```

This component uses HttpHandler clads with launches an XmlHttpRequest GET. On successful response I execute the callback function, and all is perfect excepto when I try to handle the response, the var `this.http`is undefined and I got `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.http = datos')`. It is clear I have a bad variable declaration, which would the the way to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should user React's state if you want to represent the response to an REST request. The best method to do this is `componentDidMount`. Your constructor should be something like this:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      http: "",
    }
}
```

Then, you would make the http request in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount(){
    let api = new HttpHandler();
    let podList = api.getAllPodcasts();
    let http = ""
    var that = this;
    api.getHttpResponse(responseData =>{
        let datos = responseData;
        that.setState({
            http: datos,
        });
    }, function(error){
        that.setState({
            http: error,
        });
    });
}
```

Finally, in your render method, you access the attribute http of the state:

```
 <p>API Response: {this.state.http}</p>
```

This is the way to do it in React. In the first render, http will be empty and then in `componentDidMount` it will be updated and `setState` will automatically trigger a re-render.

Comment: I think I am understanding the state just now. Still getting the error, but this time `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')`, it is possible that this is referencing the anonymous function inside `getHttpResponse()`??

Comment: It is true, it was an scope issue, I solved it adding `var that = this` before calling getHttpResponse, and, inside, `that.setState`. Please change it in your response in order to mark as correct response. And you are welcome!!!

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that :) No problem, the state is both the most important and probably confusing (at least initially) aspect of React. Also, you should probably check out [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) if your application grows.

Comment: I had read some post about using Redux, I will check it for next and bigger apps. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

**tl;dr, The problem:**

```
const _this = this
this.api.getHttpResponse(function(){
    this === _this // false
});
```

**optional solutions**

1. assign this to _this in the higher scope and use it inside the callback
2. use arrow function so it won`t create a new this inside (es6)

   ```
   const _this = this; 
   this.api.getHttpResponse(()=>{
       this === _this // true
   });
   ```
3. bind this to the callback (es5)

   ```
   var _this = this
   this.api.getHttpResponse(function(){
       this === _this // true
   }.bind(this))`
   ```